# What is the current status of Emotivism?

Tags: metaethics

> Emotivism is a meta-ethical view that claims that ethical sentences do not express propositions but emotional attitudes. Hence, it is colloquially known as the hurrah/boo theory. ([WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotivism))

I have been reading the 3<sup>rd</sup> edition of Alisdair MacIntyre's 1981 [After Virtue](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0268035040), in which he criticized contemporary moral philosophy as being inherently emotivist—which he reaffirmed 26 years later:

> For one way of framing my contention that morality is not what it once was is just to say that to a large degree people now think, talk, and act as if emotivism were true, no matter what their avowed theoretical standpoint might be. Emotivism has become embodied in our culture. (22)

[ChristopherE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/4504/christophere) recently [commented](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8516/the-blind-adherence-to-progress#comment21544_8518) on [my claim](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/8518/4556) that contemporary morality is largely emotivist:

> I'm curious: the mention of "current-day emotivism" seems out of left-field. Most ethicists working today reject emotivism (though I'm not suggesting it's wrong!). I'm not sure why you mention it.

So, I have three questions:

1. To what extent is contemporary (popular) morality emotivist?
2. To what extent is emotivism still popular among [meta]ethicists?
3. To the extent that emotivism is not popular, what has replaced it?

Comment: It's my impression that emotivism has largely been supplanted by expressivism. I can't say for sure, though, as this is well outside of my area of expertise.

Comment: Emotivism is certainly worth mentioning as one contemporary moral theory — no doubt about that. My question was about picking it out alone as a contrast for "pre-enlightenment meta-ethical moral frameworks." That is, there are a lot of other post-Enlightenment meta-ethical positions. For the same reason, I wonder if you'd reframe the question about "what has replaced" emotivism? I don't believe it's ever been the dominant meta-ethical view in English-speaking philosophy.

Comment: @ChristopherE: I'm mostly just going off of MacIntyre, whom several philosophers I respect have called 'good'. Feel free to provide an answer which questions the very premise of #2. :-) As I push through the rest of _After Virtue_ and perhaps read a few of his other books, I may be able to frame some good questions about whether this or that modern metaethic can avoid being reduced to something like emotivism. I think there may be value in my Q reflecting the viewpoint of MacIntyre?

Comment: Yes, MacIntyre *is* a good philosopher, and *After Virtue* is a worthy book. I just think the empirical data (below) show he's wrong about this, at least for early-21st-century anglophone philosophy. If you're asking, however, about how many philosophers might *secretly* be emotivists, unbeknownst to themselves, while espousing positions that contradict it, then you're asking about the conclusion to a complicated false-consciousness argument. And so you'd need to make that argument. In the absence of an argument *nobody's* — especially not an ethicist's him/herself — answer should be trusted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll focus on your Question 2 about the popularity of emotivism among contemporary meta-ethicists, and maybe the answer to 3 follows from it. Most contemporary anglophone meta-ethicists are moral realists and cognitivists (see below), but a specialist could speak better to the distribution of particular views in the subfield.

As for popular morality (Question 1), that's a question psychologists are better positioned to reply to. I know [Darcia Narvaez](http://psychology.nd.edu/faculty/faculty-by-alpha/darcia-f-narvaez/) works on the empirical analysis of moral views in the United States public, for instance.

But for Question 2:

In the November 2009 [PhilPapers survey](http://philpapers.org/surveys/), in which most of the 3226 respondents were professional philosophers including PhD students, [17% said](http://philpapers.org/surveys/results.pl) they accepted or leaned towards some form of non-cognitivism about moral judgment. (Emotivism is one form of non-cognitivism.)

Among professional philosophers with an AOS (Area of Specialization) in Meta-ethics, [15.6% (16/102) said](http://philpapers.org/surveys/linear_most_with.pl?A=profile%3aAOS%3aMeta-Ethics) they accepted or leaned towards some form of non-cognitivism about moral judgments.

Let's keep in mind that being a minority position among philosophers in no way entails being wrong!